# What does the controller hub in Crank, the SignalR test tool, do?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, crank

I am using the latest version of [SignalR and Crank](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).

I want to use the standard switches to spin up multiple simulated clients. Thus: `/NumClients:N` and `/ControllerUrl:URL`. I don't understand why I have to specify the second option when I specify the number of clients, N. I see that a single "controller hub" is started, but I don't understand why. What is it's purpose? What is it controlling?

Comment: It looks like [DCrank](https://github.com/SignalR/DCrank.git) has the architecture I expected. It is well described in [this](https://vimeo.com/113515330) presentation.

Comment: When running multiple instances of Crank (currently 7) against our application it is interesting that only one of the instances actually shows the TcpConnEst count changing. So it looks like one instance is taking "control" with the others passive. The current theory is that the controller hub is an aggregator for the data collection. Another theory is that it may be a way around the Windows outbound limit on TCP connections. This defaults to 16k but when SignalR is making connections they disappear the the rate of 3:1. So it looks like a single client has a default limit of 5k connections.

Answer (score 1):

When you use multiple clients, you have to pick one client, which will be responsible for collection of information. To achieve this, Crank try to spin own mini hub to which all other clients will connect and report information (and if you don't provide ControllerUrl which has to create this internal hub will fail).

At least, this is what I understood from reading the code.

Comment: Looking at the code it WaitsForClientsToConnect(). Which looks like it is expecting external clients to come in to the test hub. Not at all what I am expecting. I thought Crank would spin up simulated clients that will connect to my app. I don't see how the apparent behaviour helps test my application?

Comment: Well, code is quite difficult to follow. My understanding (feeling) is, that 1 thread (client) spawns hub, to which other threads (clients) connect. This internal hub is then used to coordinate actions between clients (when to connect to application under test, when load testing is finished etc.). Your application doesn't really use this hub in any way, it is internally used by Crank itself.

Comment: This echoes my understanding so far. I see that one model for test is to fire up multiple instances of Crank, each pretending to be a single client (without the /NumClients switch). I am struggling to see the Use Case for the controller hub. It looks like this acts as a sort of client concentrator? I don't see what extra you get by pointing several instances of a client (e.g. more copies of Crank) at the controller hub. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Hmm, it might be worth to ask on SignalR jabber, or directly on github. Controller hub is definitely used to coordinate those _virtual_ clients, but I can't really comment on what was reason to use this approach.